# How to install addititonal fan to my case?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, fan, dell-inspiron

Hello I want to install an additional fan on my pc (Dell Tower 3620) and I can't find any port to it and there is not any additional wire from its power supply? Is there's a solution?
I Think of connecting it on parallel with the other fan but I don't like to kill my pc like my last one :)

Comment: You need mounting space on the case (square space, grill, 4 mounting holes) and then spot (socket) on the power supply to attach the fan to. Unusual (I think) to add a fan in a manufactured PC. Make sure PS fan and CPU fan are working (not dusty) and see if there might be a 3rd fan already.

Comment: there is not any additional port of the power supply and the two fans are connected directly to the socket of the motherboard

Comment: I am not sure how you will make this modification. You need space on the case and open the power supply to create new socket. This may not be practical to do.

Comment: I think of connect it to the 5V USB to get DC Volt but not sure this will work or this will not harm the pc at least in the long term

Comment: See if the fan is 5 V  - some are 12 V.

Comment: Also make sure any fan you attach is in line with the heat flow so it can draw heat away, A fan attached so not in line with heat flow will not do any good.

Comment: sure I will but all my problem is the power supply to this fan

Comment: You need to open the power supply and find the 12 volt bus (very likely 12V) and connect into that. Fans do not draw much current.

Comment: How did the last PC die? That might guide us in what suggestions would be useful for you. It should be possible to connect the power and pwm connections in parallel with the existing fan (do not connect the speed feedback pin) by using something like 3M Scotchlok connectors.